# Variable is null when method called from Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, dictionary, jsoup

I'm making an Android application that loads a webpage and converts it to a native Android app. My plan was to have the Navigation drawer have a list of links, which would be loaded when tapped on. The problem is that when I call the page loading method from the navigation drawer, the variable it gets passed is somehow set to null. I know the variable isn't null though, because it works perfectly if the same method is called by a button. The variable in question is a Map and returns null when passed as an argument and also when I set it to public and accessed it directly.

The URL loading class:

```
public class LoadPage implements Callable<Document> {
private String URL;

private Map<String, String> cookies;


public LoadPage(String URL, Map<String, String> cookies) {
    this.URL = URL;
    //cookies is null if this gets called from the navigation drawer
    //MainActivity.cookies is also null when called from navigation drawer
    this.cookies = new HashMap<>(cookies); //This throws a null pointer exceptions, as does putAll()
}

public Document call() {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                .cookies(cookies)
                .get();
        return doc;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //handle exception
    }
}
}
```

part of MainActivity.java that handles navigation drawer selections and page loads

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
public static Map<String, String> cookies;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cookies = new HashMap<String, String>();
    cookies.put("get information passed via putExtra from login Activity);
   }
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    Log.e("something", "something");
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
    loadPage(null);
}
//omitted code
public void loadPage(View v) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<Document> request = executor.submit(new LoadPage("Example.com", cookies));
    try {
        Document page = request.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Elements elements = page.select("criteria for item selection");
        currentPage = page;
        ArrayList<TopicLink> topics = new ArrayList<TopicLink>(elements.size());
        mTitle = page.title();
        restoreActionBar();
        for (Element e : elements) {
            //send data to adapter class for listview population
        }
        TopicAdapter adapter = new TopicAdapter(this, R.id.listview, topics);
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {

    } catch (TimeoutException e) {

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

For some reason, loadPage does just fine when called by a button, but when called via the navigation drawer, the cookies Map just becomes null.

Edit: the logcat

```
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cookie map must not be null
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.HyperStandard.llr.app.MainActivity.loadPage(MainActivity.java:248)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.HyperStandard.llr.app.MainActivity.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(MainActivity.java:136)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.HyperStandard.llr.app.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:245)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.HyperStandard.llr.app.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreate(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:98)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.HyperStandard.llr.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
06-20 20:22:34.783  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cookie map must not be null
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:26)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.cookies(HttpConnection.java:139)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.HyperStandard.llr.app.LoadPage.call(LoadPage.java:40)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.HyperStandard.llr.app.LoadPage.call(LoadPage.java:20)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
06-20 20:22:34.793  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cookie map must not be null
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.HyperStandard.llr.app.MainActivity.loadPageURL(MainActivity.java:318)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.HyperStandard.llr.app.MainActivity.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(MainActivity.java:142)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.HyperStandard.llr.app.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:245)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.HyperStandard.llr.app.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreate(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:98)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.HyperStandard.llr.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cookie map must not be null
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:26)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.cookies(HttpConnection.java:139)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.HyperStandard.llr.app.LoadPage.call(LoadPage.java:40)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at com.HyperStandard.llr.app.LoadPage.call(LoadPage.java:20)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
06-20 20:22:34.803  22835-22835/com.HyperStandard.llr.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)
```

I tried messing with alternate constructors and so on to initialize the Map but they all threw some variant of NullPointerException

Comment: can you post the logcat?

Comment: Check if there are any null values at MainActivity.java:77

Comment: in your itemSelected, you are calling the method by passing value 'null', you have to change that.

Comment: MainActivity.java is setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
And that's a valid xml file.
I thought it might be the null value being passed but I made a duplicate method without the View parameter and it has the same error. It tries to reference a value that is null despite being defined in the code.